# Computed column performance

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, calculated-columns

I can't find any answer for my problem on the web.

When exactly are computed columns computed? (not persisted ones)

When I select TOP 100 from thousands of records, are they calculated for only those selected rows?
What if I add a WHERE clause for the computed column? Does this change?

The main problem is that I have a one to many relationship, but I want to have information on parent side about... let's say MAX(somecolumn) of child table. 
I'm using Entity Framework. I decided to make a computed column.
Is this a good idea? Are there any others? Any help appreciated. Tnx

EDIT:
My column is defined like this:

```
[ComputedNextClassDate] as [dbo].[ComputeNextClassDate]([Id]),
```

And my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ComputeNextClassDate](@id INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @nextDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();
SELECT  @nextDate = MIN(Start) FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE [Start] > @now AND [GroupClassId] = @id
RETURN @nextDate;
END;
```

Comment: You cannot make such a computed column. It can only be computed from column values of the same table.

Comment: So how do you call a column based on user defined function in which I have sql statements?

Comment: Ok I wasn't thinking of that. That will easily result in very bad performance because the function is not inlined into the query plan. Search for "sql server function performance" to find all the pitfalls.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that EF will read the computed value on every read but also _each insert and edit_ of `Class`. It's easy enough to query the value with EF when required. (And it keeps the business logic in one place). I guess it depends on how often you need it.

Comment: Thanks, @GertArnold. This was an undisclosed hazard that bit us recently. It turns out in some cases, EF will even generate multiple selects for the same query, which doubled the execution time of our queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the calculated columns with no persistance, the calculation result is never stored. 
On query execution, SQL Server engine search an execution plan. If your query has been well written, the value will be calculated only once even if it is used at many places into your query.

My opinion, I never use calculated columns with no persistence. The calculation must be done at the insertion or when reading. SQL Server, and others, are ineficient for calculation usually. 
Call the CLR is catastrophic in terms of performance. Avoid it.

Prefer multiples tables with joins like

```
SELECT p.product_name
    , SUM(ISNULL(sales,0)) 
FROM product p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_name
```

Comment: Thanks, so you state that it's better to generate a view like this?

Comment: Yes, as you only have to perform simple calculations (+,-).